# Multiply filter kernel by sine

Tags: dft, lowpass-filter, homework, bandpass

1)Suppose that we have low-pass filter with cf equal to 0.1. How frequency response would look like  if I multiply filter kernel by sine with frequency say 0.3?  How this is related to converting 
low-pass filter algorithm into  bandpass filter?

2)What is the difference between multiplying filter kernel by sine and cosine?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I'm still don't quite understand the difference between multiplying  filter kernel by sine and cosine. It is said that with help of cosine it is possible to transform lpf to hpf. But I don't understand why?

Frequency spectrum for cosine is similar to sine (is it?) So what's the difference?

Thanks in advance again.

Comment: I found answer on my question [here][1]. 


  [1]: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15912/why-multiplying-frequency-kernel-with-sinusoid-results-shifting-frequency-domain